# Get target control from DoubleAnimation Completed event in WPF?

Tags: wpf, animation

I'm hoping someone can help me with what I thought would be a relatively straight forward problem.

I am setting a fadeout animation in code using a DoubleAnimation object. It fades out an image, and then fires off the Completed event when it's done.

I would like to get the name of the control that the fadeout animation was applied to from within the event handler, but I can't find a way.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

```
DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    image1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    image2.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;

    timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
    timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
    timer.Start();
}

void FadeOut(UIElement element)
{
    DoubleAnimation FadeOut = new DoubleAnimation(1, 0, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5)));
    FadeOut.Completed += new EventHandler(FadeOut_Completed);
    element.BeginAnimation(OpacityProperty, FadeOut);
}

void FadeOut_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // How to find out which control was targeted?
}

void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (image1.Visibility == System.Windows.Visibility.Visible)
    {
        FadeOut(image1); 
        //image1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
        //image2.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    }
}
```

Comment: sender? The target for this animation is not explicitly set, so if it works it's definitely sender

Comment: How do I explicitly set the target? PS. Updated the code to include the timer tick event.

Comment: I was somewhat wrong, but found a solution. See my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code gives you the target of completed animation. Place it in FadeOut_Completed() handler:

```
DependencyObject target = Storyboard.GetTarget(((sender as AnimationClock).Timeline as AnimationTimeline))
```

However this will only work if animation target object is specified. To do it add the following to FadeOut() method:

```
Storyboard.SetTarget(FadeOut, element);
```